# Checking if all bolean elements in a list are the same in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wanna check if boolean elements in a list are all True, all False, or both True and False. Here is my code for now:

```
data Answer3 = Just_True | Just_False | Both deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
type A3 = Answer3


checkBoolean :: [Bool] -> A3
checkBoolean (x:x1:xs) = if (length (x:x1:xs) `mod` 2) == 0  
                            then if (x && x1) && checkBoolean'(x1:xs)== True
                                     then Just_True
                                     else if (x && x1) == True
                                             then Both
                                             else if checkBoolean'(xs)== True
                                                     then Both
                                                     else Just_False


                            else if x && checkBoolean'(x1:xs) == True
                                    then Just_True
                                    else if x == False
                                            then Just_False
                                            else Both 

checkBoolean':: [Bool] -> Bool
checkBoolean' (x:xs) = x && (checkBoolean'(xs))
checkBoolean' [] = True
```

Calling

```
*Main> checkBoolean [False, False, False]
Just_False
```

or

```
*Main> checkBoolean [True, True, True]
Just_True
```

or

```
*Main> checkBoolean [True, False, False]
Both
```

gives correct result. But

```
*Main> checkBoolean [False, False, True, False, True]
Just_False
```

and

```
*Main> checkBoolean [False, False, True]
Just_False
```

do not work as I intended. `[False, False, True, False, True]` is Both, and  `[False, False, True]` is also Both

I know I didn't think all possible cases and thats why this doesn't work, but is there an efficient way to write this without writing this much if else statements?

Comment: You're calling `checkBoolean'` in your code, but it isn't defined.

Comment: @Jorge Adriano edited

Comment: Currently `checkBoolean []` fails. Is that how it is supposed to behave?

Comment: @ Jorge Adriano I didn't intend to pass `[]` to my function thats why I didn't write that. But I think I will go with answer bellow for now

Comment: No need for creating a new data structure, why not just use `Maybe Bool`? This handles all 3 cases.

Comment: FYI: `all` handles `[ ]`. all (==True) [ ]` is `True`, `all (==False)` is `True`, `all (==True) [True]` is `True`. `all (==False) [True,False]` is `False`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh wow, you kinda overcomplicated it.

There's a very useful function called [`all`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/all_f.html):

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

It checks all elements for a predicate, which for booleans could be just a pair of `id` and `not` functions, but you can also explicitly check equality to a value, which makes for pretty readable code:

```
checkBoolean xs = 
    if all (== True) xs then Just_True
    else if all (== False) xs then Just_False
    else Both
```

It's probably also a good idea to be somewhat more explicit about the empty list (`[]`) case. Should it be `Just_True`, `Just_False`, `Both`, or perhaps another value altogether?

Comment: Simple true, but surely in this kind of educational exercise he should try doing it with a single traversal.

Comment: It is worth discussing the use of `(== True)` and `(== False)`. While they are correct, they are unusual and it might be more expected or common to see `id` and `not` instead.

Comment: @DietrichEpp If you look at the edit history, you'll see that that's how the first version looked. I thought that the more explicit one would be a bit more readable for a beginner. In principle I agree that `== True` is a code smell.

Comment: @JorgeAdriano I am not sure about the "surely" part. I don't know what's the goal of the exercise, and I'd probably write it in such a way was this my actual code.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a case for the empty list? I wouldn't expect `checkBoolean [] = Just_True` to hold.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Hard to tell without asking OP, I suppose. Really depends on where this thing is supposed to be used, but I can mention it.

Comment: Well, `all f []` is true for any f, so why not output `Just_False` instead?

Comment: What is the function supposed to do if the list is empty?

Comment: `all (== True)` same as `all id` same as `and`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I guess you're right. And indeed this short, very readable, and `all` is even in the Prelude, it is  a pretty neat solution.

Answer (score 10):

The functions `all` or `any` come to mind first:

```
any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
```

If we specialize for lists, we replace `t` with `[]`, which makes this looks like:

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

We can compare all of the elements to the first element to see if the list contains all the same value. If any elements are different, then we know that the list is mixed.

```
checkBoolean (x:xs)
      -- Check if any elements are not equal to the first one.
    | any (/= x) xs = Both
    | x             = Just_True
    | otherwise     = Just_False
```

We might want to handle the degenerate case as well:

```
-- "Just_True" is arbitrary... you could say "Just_False", too.
checkBoolean [] = Just_True
```

It is worth noting that as an exercise, you find it valuable to write the function recursively, without the use of higher-order functions like `all` or `any`, even though they are in the prelude. Here is an alternative, tail-recursive implementation:

```
checkBoolean [] = Just_True
checkBoolean (x:xs) = check xs
  where
    check [] = if x
               then Just_True
               else Just_False
    check (y:ys) = if x == y
                   then check ys
                   else Both
```

I would not expect to see this longer version in actual project code.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a case to handle empty lists:

```
-- checkBoolean [] = Neither
data Answer4 = Just_True | Just_False | Both | Neither
```

`Answer4` has a simple, if long-winded, `Semigroup` instance.

```
instance Semigroup Answer4 where
    -- like combines with like
    Just_True <> Just_True = Just_True
    Just_False <> Just_False = Just_False
    -- Neither is "like" anything
    x <> Neither = x
    Neither <> x  = x
    -- otherwise, you get Both
    _ <> _ = Both
```

and a simple `Monoid` instance:

```
instance Monoid Answer4 where
    mempty = Neither
```

Now, if you have a way of converting a `Bool` to an `Answer4`

```
lift :: Bool -> Answer4
lift True = Just_True
lift False = Just_False
```

you can reduce a list of `Bool` to a single `Answer4` value quickly:

```
-- foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
-- Here, t ~ [], a ~= Bool, and  m ~ Answer4, for a specialized type
-- foldMap :: (Bool -> Answer4) -> [Bool] -> Answer4
checkBoolean :: [Bool] -> Answer4
checkBoolean = foldMap lift
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of this, because it's not tail recursive. The `<>` operations will stack up.

Comment: One could use one of the various strict folds instead of `foldMap`, e.g. `foldl' (<>) mempty . map lift`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the pre-available functions on lists, you should consider,

```
partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

available in `Data.List`. Using this function you can partition your list into a pair `(ts,fs)` where `ts` and `fs` are respectively the list with all the `True` and all the `False` elements of the original list. Then you just have to check if neither is empty, or if only one of them is and which. You can also decide what to return in the case where both are empty.

Note that with this implementation, the traversal of the list stops as soon as both a `True` and a `False` element are found. Because that's enough to know neither list in the partition pair is empty. This is a desirable property for a solution of this problem, i.e. once you have gathered enough information to know the answer, you should stop and return the result.

---

At this point though, considering your own attempt at solving the problem, I'd suggest you should perhaps be focusing on building your own recursive solution.

Comment: This retains memory unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps easier this way

```
checkBoolean xs | and xs        = Just_True
                | (not . or) xs = Just_False
                | otherwise     = Both
```

Comment: @dfeuer, not really.  Since the first element is either `True` or `False`, one of the traversal will surely exit after the first element.  The worst case is all `True` or all `False` for which full traversal is required (but only once!)

Comment: you're right that only one traversal will complete. But barring an extremely unlikely Haskell evaluation strategy, one of them will be chosen to run first. This means that under unfavorable circumstances, the entire list will be retained in memory so that the second one (sure to terminate immediately) can be run.

Comment: so, it's a memory issue, or more precisely delays GC.

Comment: yes. I initially thought it was more, but that's what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern matching can probably integrated into `checkBoolean` but the main observation is that we don't need check all elements twice: we check for membership of True and False anyway, so from `not (elem True xs)` we can conclude that the list is either empty or only contains False. For that I'll extend Answer3 by the `None` case.

```
data Answer3 = Just_True | Just_False | Both | None deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

cat True  True  = Both
cat True  False = Just_True
cat False True  = Just_False
cat False False = None

checkBoolean xs = cat (elem True xs) (elem False xs)
```

Comment: You may still traverse part of the list twice.

Comment: The first element of xs is either True or False, so one of the `elem`s terminates after one step. The other `elem` terminates at most after `length xs` steps (in case the list is uniform). @chepner's solution even needs to look at one element less.

Comment: True. But you still retain the list longer than necessary.

Comment: In what way longer than necessary? Do you have an example in mind where the traversal could terminate earlier?

Comment: If there are only `False` values and the `elem True xs` test is performed first, then the whole list/stream will be retained until the end, in case the other test is required.